# IDockableWindow ability to auto size?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, vb.net, add-in

I have a ArcObjects 10.2 vb.net Custom Add-in that is a dockable window.  The dockable window displayes a windows form that has listboxes, textboxes, panels, tab panels, etc. that the user interacts with.   I'm trying to get it so that when the window is not docked it autosizes like a windows form.  I want certain controls on the form to grow/shrink when the dockable window is resized.  I'm struggling to get this to work and wonder if it is even possible.  If I anchor the controls on all sides they overlap each other in the dockable window. I've tried multiple combinations of anchors, autosizing modes on both the dockable window and the form.

I have looked at resizing the window here: 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Resize_Dockable_Window_Snippet/004900000077000000/

Moving the window here:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Report_Dockable_Window_Position_Snippet/0049000000qq000000/

And creating a fixed size here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143623/creation-of-fixed-size-dockable-window

I haven't found anything that shows how this can be accomplished.  Is there away to get the dockable window to act like a windows form with the same autosizing properties and still dock to ArcMap?

Comment: Does your form resize correctly when not in a dockable window?  Is the dockable window content a form or a user control?